# Error al compilar : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: paquete1.Principal

Tags: java

He encontrado el siguiente error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class paquete1.Principal Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: paquete1.Principal
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\15\executor-snippets\run.xml:111:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\15\executor-snippets\run.xml:94:
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Esto me sucede al compilar el siguiente proyecto:

```
package paquete1;

public class Cuadrilatero {
    
    // ATRIBUTOS
    
    private float lado1;
    private float lado2;
    
    
    // MÉTODOS
    
    public Cuadrilatero (float lado1, float lado2) {
        
        this.lado1= lado1;
        this.lado2 = lado2;
        
    }
    
    public Cuadrilatero (float lado1) {
        
        this.lado1= this.lado2 = lado1;  // Como un cuadrado se compone de dos lados iguales, el lado uno se equivale al lado 2
        
    }
    
    // Getters y Setters
    
    public float getPerimetro () {
        
        float perimetro = 2*(lado1+lado2);
        return perimetro;
    }
    
    public float getArea () {
        
        float area = lado1*lado2;
        return area;
    }
}
```

---

```
package paquete1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Cuadrilatero c1;
        float lado1, lado2;
        
        lado1= Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el lado1:"));
        lado2= Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el lado2:"));
        
        if (lado1==lado2) { // Es un cuadrado
            
            c1 = new Cuadrilatero (lado1);
        }
        else {
            c1 = new Cuadrilatero (lado1,lado2);
        }
               
    }

}
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Pienso que tiene que ver cuando instalé `SQL Workbench`, pero no estoy seguro.

Estoy usando Eclipse, pero usé Netbeans con la esperanza de que el error no continuara. Importé el proyecto de Eclipse y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: puede que La clase esta declarada  en el paquete incorrecto. o la ruta del archivo de la clase  no coincide con el nombre completo.

Comment: ¿Cómo soluciono eso?

Comment: poniendola en el paquete correcto y/o corrigiendo el nombre de la clase ;3